# Expand environment variables in appSettings.json file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Is there a way "out of the box" to have environment variables in `appsettings.json` values expanded automatically?

To take a contrived example:

```
{
  ...
  "MyPath1": "C:/MyApp/%ENV%/Myfolder1/MyFile1.dat",
  "MyConnectionString":  "Server=MyServer%ENV%..."
  ...
}
```

My objective is to be able to switch my environment by changing a single environment variable, and have it affect multiple appsetting values, rather than having per-environment configuration files.

**UPDATE**

I've looked through [the source code of JsonConfigurationProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/master/src/Config.Json/JsonConfigurationProvider.cs) and as far as I can see there is no such feature out of the box.

I can see that it should be possible by deriving a custom class from `JsonConfigurationProvider` and overriding the `Load()` method:

```
public override void Load()
{
    base.Load();
    foreach(var key in Data.Keys)
    {
        Data[key] = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(key);
    }
}
```

But I'm quite new to .NET Core configuration, which leads to a second question:

How do I get this custom implementation to replace the standard one?  I.e. to remove the default appsettings.json and appsettings.environment.json providers and replace by the custom one.  Presumably something to be added in `Program.cs`:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.??? what do I need here?
        }
        );
```

Comment: I think you have found the only solution, else take a search through github/nuget.

Comment: There are a few options for `ConfigureAppConfiguration`. The default setup does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#default-configuration) (see the last bullet, "App configuration is provided from:"). Do you still want all of those sources, in the same order, or can you simplify? e.g. Can you just have one source, which is the `appsettings.json` file with the env replacement?

Comment: @KirkLarkin - I ideally want to replace the first two sources, appsettings.json and appsettings.{Environment}.json.  So that it behaves like the default configuration which other developers would be familiar with except that it adds environment variable expansion.

Comment: i would say you have two choice: 1 read the configuration and just replace the "placeholder" with your environment.... but that is just hacky... i would just use the normal multi file system available in .net core already like appsettings.json and appsetings.environmentname.json

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To create and use a custom configuration source, two implementations are needed:

1. [`IConfigurationSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationsource?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)
2. [`IConfigurationProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

It's the `IConfigurationSource` implementation that gets added to the `IConfigurationBuilder`'s sources. This implementation is also responsible for creating its own `IConfigurationProvider`, which is reponsible for loading the data from the source.

Here's both a custom implementation of `IConfigurationSource` (`ExpandJsonConfigurationSource`) and `IConfigurationProvider` (`ExpandJsonConfigurationProvider`):

```
public class ExpandJsonConfigurationSource : JsonConfigurationSource
{
    public override IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        EnsureDefaults(builder);
        return new ExpandJsonConfigurationProvider(this);
    }
}

public class ExpandJsonConfigurationProvider : JsonConfigurationProvider
{
    public ExpandJsonConfigurationProvider(ExpandJsonConfigurationSource source)
        : base(source) { }

    public override void Load()
    {
        base.Load();
        Data = Data.ToDictionary(
            x => x.Key,
            x => Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(x.Value),
            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

There's not a lot going on here. These implementations just follow the same approach as the existing `JsonConfigurationSource` and `JsonConfigurationProvider` implementations, with custom processing for expanding the environment variables.

To replace the preconfigured JSON-based sources, use the following:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
        {
            var jsonConfigurationSources = builder.Sources
                .OfType<JsonConfigurationSource>()
                .ToList();

            foreach (var jsonConfigurationSource in jsonConfigurationSources)
            {
                var indexOfJsonConfigurationSource = builder.Sources
                    .IndexOf(jsonConfigurationSource);

                builder.Sources.RemoveAt(indexOfJsonConfigurationSource);
                builder.Sources.Insert(
                    indexOfJsonConfigurationSource,
                    new ExpandJsonConfigurationSource
                    {
                        FileProvider = jsonConfigurationSource.FileProvider,
                        Path = jsonConfigurationSource.Path,
                        Optional = jsonConfigurationSource.Optional,
                        ReloadOnChange = jsonConfigurationSource.ReloadOnChange
                    });
            }
        });
```

The delegate passed in to `ConfigureAppConfiguration` does the following:

1. Locate all configured instances of `JsonConfigurationSource`. There should be two instances: for `appsettings.json` and for e.g. `appsettings.Development.json`.
2. For each instance:

   1. Determine the position of the instance within the preconfigured sources.
   2. Remove the instance.
   3. Replace the removed instance with an instance of `ExpandJsonConfigurationSource`, copying across the properties to ensure it has the same path, optional flag, etc.

Comment: Awesome to get an answer from the person who wrote the Microsoft documentation on the subject! I suppose that if I know that there are no other sources, I can simply do "configuration.Sources.Clear();" as they do in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider, and then add.

Comment: @GöranRoseen Yeah, that's right. You get full control by doing that but you lose the defaults, of course.

Answer (score 8):

I created a library to perform variable substitution, it substitutes from *any* configuration source, not just environment variables.
See: https://github.com/molinch/ConfigurationSubstitutor

You just need to register it as another configuration source, this is done by calling `.EnableSubstitutions()` on the ConfigurationBuilder.

With your example:

- if in appsettings.json you have: `"MyPath": "C:/MyApp/%ENV%/Myfolder1/MyFile1.dat"`
- and you have the following environment variable: `ENV = Foo`
- then you should enable substitutions so:

```cs
.EnableSubstitutions("%", "%")
```

Finally when requesting MyPath from the configuration you will get: `C:/MyApp/Foo/Myfolder1/MyFile1.dat`