# Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration value substitution

Tags: c#, serilog

#### Motivation

I have a bunch of applications for which to configure logging and I want to share that configuration if possible. Each application uses a different application path however and I was looking for a way to substitute `$(ProcessName)` below with the process name.

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": {
      "TextFile": {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "$(ProcessName).txt",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Requirements

I'm aware I can override `"Serilog:WriteTo:TextFile:Args:path"` in code, but that fixes the sink name to `TextFile` and it will always be present regardless of the sink.

Essentially I'm looking to perform a transformation on Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration before Serilog consumes it. Hot reloading needs to work so a one-time transform won't do.

#### Attempts

1. Create my own configuration source/provider (I'm aware this is not serilog specific) but I couldn't get it to work
2. Look at ReloadToken to see if I can just write a handler which will rewrite the configuration every time it changes but ReloadToken is pretty darn unergonomic to work with.

Important pieces of the configuration source/provider wrapper:

```cs
public class SubstitutionConfigurationSource : IConfigurationSource
{
    private readonly IConfigurationSource _inner;
    private readonly IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _substitutions;
...
    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder) => new SubstitutionConfigurationProvider(_inner.Build(builder), _substitutions);
}

public class SubstitutionConfigurationProvider: IConfigurationProvider
{
    private readonly IConfigurationProvider _inner;
    private readonly IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _substitutions;
...
    public bool TryGet(string key, out string value)
    {
        if (!_inner.TryGet(key, out value)) return false;

        value = Substitute(value);
        return true;
    }

    private string Substitute(string value)
    {
        foreach (var (key, val) in _substitutions)
        {
            value = value.Replace(key, val);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

```cs
IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.Add(new SubstitutionConfigurationSource(
        // The JsonConfigurationSource can't find the file unfortunately. Stopped persuing this approach because of it.
        new JsonConfigurationSource
        {
            FileProvider = configurationBuilder.GetFileProvider(),
            Path = "serilog.json"
            Optional = false,
            ReloadOnChange = true,
        },
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
        {
            new ("$(ProcessName)", processName),
        }
        )
    )
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true);
```

#### Question

I can't imagine myself being the only one who looked for this. What should I be doing? Switch to another programming language?

Comment: There are a myriad of ways to do that.Do you use a release pipeline like Azure Devops, Octopus deploy, etc? These tools have the capability to transform configuration at release time.

Comment: Would that work during development? If I can prevent it, I'd like to share common configuration rather than generate copies.

Comment: No, during development you have many options. I suggest you [read through them all](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0), and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0). You can choose configuration based on `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`, with user settings, environment variables, and the list goes on.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with providing different configurations in different environments. I have multiple applications (20) which all need logging configured, and rather than generating 20 config files I want these applications to import a common config file. I'd like the common config file to be able to use the process name to specify the log file path. Generating 20 config files is undesireable because of the maintenance burden.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60713876/5339918

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do what I did and use Environmental variables which i set by hand in code:

```cs
// Set environmental variables that can be used inside appSettings.json
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("CUROUTDIR", OPGPathManager.CurrentOutputDirectory);

var processName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSNAME", PathHelpers.ReplaceInvalidChars(processName, '_'));
```

Just run that code before you load your config.
And then you can do something like:

```json
"path": "%CUROUTDIR%\\..\\Logs\\%PROCESSNAME%\\%PROCESSNAME% .txt",
```

EDIT:
Oddly enough i can't find any documentation about appsettings.json being capable of expanding env. variables like this. It could be that this is a feature of serilog or just appsettings in general - but this works for my serilog file sink right now.

There are also substitution libraries out there which can handle this kind of thing, like:

https://github.com/molinch/ConfigurationSubstitutor